# Command to list all usernames on a Linux server

Tags: shell-script, users, passwd

What is the command that allows one to generate a list of all the usernames of authorised users on a Linux server? I have tried

```
getent passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs groups
```

and

```
less /etc/passwd
```

and

```
grep 'x:0:' /etc/passwd
```

and

```
getent passwd
```

and

```
grep "/bin/bash" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

but none of the above gives me exactly what I want, which is simply a list of usernames.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your first attempt, but remove the `| xargs groups`. Really, though, this is basic enough that it's not all that appropriate for this site...

Answer (score 0):

awk(1) is another useful tool.  awk is able to parse individual fields from lines of text, based on a specified delimiter.  In the case of /etc/passwd, that delimiter is a colon, hence we pass '-F:' on the awk command line.  Likewise, since the user name is the first field of the line, and awk numbers fields beginning at 1, we stipulate 'print $1' to tell awk to print the first field of each line.

```
awk -F: '{ print $1 }' < /etc/passwd
```

This can easily be adapted to print any field from the passwd file.  Here is a list of each user's name (field 1), followed by a space, followed by their login shell (field 7):

```
awk -F: '{ print $1, $7 }' < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Yesterday we were discussing `ls` options in the comments on the (now deleted) question [Can't move a directory into other one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715826/80216).  I’ve learned that we were comparing apples and oranges.  In (some version of) OpenBSD, `ls` [has a `-o` option](https://man.openbsd.org/ls) that means “Include the file flags in a long (`-l`) output.”  Apparently Apple copied this in OS X, but, in (some version of) macOS, they [moved that function to `-O` (capital ‘o’)](https://ss64.com/osx/ls.html) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and added `-o` to be the same as in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html): “List in long format, but omit the group id.”  So, I apologize if my comments to you were harsh.  But you should be aware that ```ls -o``` doesn’t mean the same [in GNU](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) or POSIX as it does in whatever system you’re using.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' No apology necessary, G-Man.  I'm often remiss to check whether my advice is applicable to other OSes, especially when the OP may not have indicated an OS at all.

Answer (score 0):

This will filter users by who has a shell:

```bsh
getent passwd | egrep  '(/bin/bash)|(/bin/zsh)|(/bin/sh)' | cut -f1 -d:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for a list of authorized users,
and indicated that you mean for this to be a subset of the list of all users,
but you have not identified what criteria you want to use
to distinguish between authorized users and unauthorized users.

Systems (Unix and Windows) often come with standard,
builtin users predefined: `root`, `bin`, `mail` and `news` in Unix;
`Administrator`, `SYSTEM`, `LOCAL SERVICE` and `TrustedInstaller` on Windows. 
On Unix, “real” users (assigned to real people)
typically have a GID ≥ 500 and a home directory in `/home`. 
The system users usually fail both these criteria. 
So we can list the users in `/etc/passwd` that meet these criteria with

```
awk -F: '$6 ~ /^\/home/ && $3 >= 500 {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

If `getent passwd` produces users that aren’t in `/etc/passwd`,
you can just hook them up:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$6 ~ /^\/home/ && $3 >= 500 {print $1}'
```

or combine them:

```
getent passwd | sort -u - /etc/passwd | awk -F: '$6 ~ /^\/home/ && $3 >= 500 {print $1}'
```

Note: This answer is based on [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158803/80216#158810) (now deleted, 10K only)
by [Chema](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86418/chema).

Comment: Oh man, how embarrassing... I was still trying to motivate people to Google basic questions before posting back then.  Funny that it was deleted for not providing an answer to the question, when I included two.  In any case, they are not mine, as I followed my own advice and found them on Google.  :)

Comment: I do wonder: why bother notifying me about a trivial command?

Comment: On Stack Exchange, up is down, talking eggs sit on walls, cats disappear (there’s a double meaning there), and people celebrate the trivial.  Happy π Day (it’s still 22/7 in the western hemisphere). But I notified you, not because I posted a trivial answer, but because I attributed it to you.  Would you prefer that I remove your name?

Comment: Haha, Cheshireness always leaves me a smile, but I have yet to talk to eggs --though I threaded over some earlier, rather clumsily, while talking to the Queen.  After that, I can't fathom the (miss)attribution to be of any consequence, so do as you will.  Happeeapplepie aprox!